# WEKA : Is there a way to provide huge data in chunks as a test set?

Tags: java, weka, naivebayes

I am using weka GUI for predicting a class(producttype) in a multiclass classification problem.

My training and test sets are completely different. I am training my data set on 1M instances and currently the test set has 700K instances.

I want to test the model on 20 M instances.
So is there a way that i can have a loop going on once the first 700 are done with testing, i can move ahead with the next 700 until all the 20 M instances are covered.

Note : I do not want to increase my Training set but i want to keep increasing the test data set.

Any guidance or idea on this will be appreciated.